# Pass dynamic connection string to perform DB operation using EF 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

I have created one web API and used Entity Framework 6 for DB operation, I have the logic below to get data from DB.

```
<connectionStrings><add name="DB" connectionString="server=DESKTOP-DB; uid=sa;pwd=111111;database=EmpDB;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /></connectionStrings>

public void SaveData(string data1, long data2){
DatabaseProviderFactory factory = new DatabaseProviderFactory();
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database db = factory.Create("DB");
DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("EmpSave");
using (DbConnection connection = db.CreateConnection())
{
    DbTransaction trans = null;
    try
    {
        trans = connection.BeginTransaction();
        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@EMPID", DbType.Int64, data2);
        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@name", DbType.String, data1);
        db.ExecuteNonQuery(dbCommand, trans);
        trans.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        trans.Rollback();
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        trans.Dispose();
        connection.Close();
    }
}
}
```

Now I want to use dynamic connection string for DB operation, means in request I will receive one parameter, based on parameter value I will retrieve connection string from DB/XML and use the same in DB operation, so data will be stored based on value of Parameter received in request.

Any ideas on how to achieve this using the logic above?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your connection string is in app.config with name = "DB". 
You can use below approach:

```
if(parameter1)
{ 
   string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ConnectionString;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response, I have configured connection string in App.config which is default, but I want to change it to use another DB runtime for each request based on parameter value. For e.g. Param = 1 then I want use Connection string = ABC, for Param = 2 then I want to use Connection string = XYZ.

Comment: In case, if you want to maintain multiple connection string in app.config, you can use above code to get the required connection string by passing "connection string name" in above code. If you would like to use single connection string and modify the same depending on parameters, that also possible to do using above code. Is thisnot working?

Comment: Instead of hard coding DB credentials in App.config, you can replace these at runtime after reading connection string from app.config.